# How in RecyclerView with custom first element make first element height equals to size of the screeen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Container:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/photos_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.photos}"
            tools:itemCount="100"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_view_item" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Title (TextView just for example. It with the button must fill all the screen):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="@string/button_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In layout editor it looks like this:
[layout editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH7y7.png)
But in application it height is shrinked to content:
[application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeM6O.png)

Repository with test project is here: https://github.com/Andrey-Metelyov/Just_Image_Gallery

Comment: I think android:layout_height="match_parent" does not work here because parent of this element is not ConstraintLayout, which have size of screen, but just element in RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in inflate:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_TITLE -> PicsumPhotoTitleViewHolder(TitleViewItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)), viewModel)
        ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> PicsumPhotoViewHolder(ListViewItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
        else -> throw ClassCastException("Unknown viewType $viewType")
    }
}
```

should be:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_TITLE -> PicsumPhotoTitleViewHolder(TitleViewItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)**, parent, false**), viewModel)
        ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> PicsumPhotoViewHolder(ListViewItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
        else -> throw ClassCastException("Unknown viewType $viewType")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u have 2 ways for doing what u want
the first one: u must create 2 different view types and separate layout with different layout on each of them
the second one: u can add custom parameter in your viewdata model and change layout params on view depends on it

Comment: I already have two different view types. How to change layout parameters?

Comment: you must set new layout params to your holder's view like this 
```lp = yourView.getLayoutParams()
lp.width = width
lp.height = height
view.layoutParams = lp```